# slick set active elememnt

Tags: slick.js

how to set active element from js when slick shows all slides without any arrows ?

The only thing I have found is this

```
$('#carousel').slick('slickGoTo',10);
```

but it only work when there are arrows , and does not work when screen is wide enought to hidde arrows.

Answer (score 0):

i found and the answer is to use this function setSlideClasses